# How to implement dynamic filter functionality in the Tree Table in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, treetable

I am trying to implement the dynamic filter functionality in SAPUI5 Tree Table but unable to get the desired results. The filter value from the view is passed correctly to the controller but the filter is not getting applied to the table. Following is the code snippet that is used in the program.

- View

```js
<table:TreeTable id="treeTable" rows="{path:'/SalesOrderSet', parameters: {arrayNames:['SalesOrderItemSet']}}" 
  selectionMode="None" filter="sofilter">
  <table:columns type="Navigation">
   <table:Column showSortMenuEntry="true" sortProperty="Countid" filterProperty="SalesOrderId"
    defaultFilterOperator="Contains" >
    <table:template>
     <Text text="{SalesOrderId}"/>
    </table:template>
   </table:Column>
  </table:columns>
 </table:TreeTable>
```

- Controller

```js
sofilter: function(oEvt) {
 
 var filterValue = oEvt.getParameters().value;
 var filterOperator = oEvt.getParameters().column.mProperties.filterOperator;
 var filterProperty = oEvt.getParameters().column.mProperties.filterProperty;
 var oTreeTable = this.getView().byId("SalesOrderSet");
 var oBinding = oTreeTable.getBinding("rows");
 var filterArray = [];

 filterArray.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter({
  path: filterProperty,
  operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,
  value1: filterValue
 }));
 oBinding.filter(filterArray);

}
```

Comment: Table should be referenced by it's id in the filter method: `var oTreeTable = this.getView().byId("treeTable");`

Comment: I have corrected the code with the Treetable id, but still, it is not working.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle from the code, I cannot see more errors in the code